# Windows Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to execute a Set of SQL scripts using a batch bile. When I try this Windows batch file it doesn't run. Please tell me know how to write the script to loop through the files?

My script:

```
sqlcmd -S tcp:LENOVO-GH1C00\SAM -U UserName -P PassWord -i c:\SQLCMDSCRIPTS\SELECT.SQL -o C:\SELECT.txt -p -b

IF NOT [%ERRORLEVEL%] ==[0] goto get_Error

:Success
echo Finished Succesffuly
exit /B 0
goto end

:get_error
echo step Failed
exit /B 40

:end
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? Can you run the sqlcmd step manually at a command prompt and see what happens?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the `FOR` statement. At a `CMD.EXE` prompt type `help for` for more information.

Here is the general for for iterating over a set of files:

```
FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
```

For your needs you might do something like:

```
FOR %f IN (c:\SQLCMDSCRIPTS\*.SQL) DO sqlcmd ... -i %f ...
```

but you'll have to adapt it to fit what you're trying to do and you'll probably have to do the error handling differently.